# sort dataframe using MULTIINDEX

Tags: python, pandas, stack, multi-index

I am a newbie and in a huge need of help of changeing my dataframe with use of multi-indexing,

How my dataframe looks like, Notice Reading it from a csv file.

[image]

How I want it to look,

[image]

Please someone help me, I have been with this for long time. I have tried the stack function but it doesn't work well at all. Please help me..

What i have managed to do is to:

```
import pandas as pd
```

path = "C:\Desktop\data.csv" 
df=pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post a snippet of your data frame or at least code to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called .stack().
Docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking

An example:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_ = {
    "date": [2017,2016,2015,2014],
    "total members": [150,140,100,150],
    "lions": [20,10,5,50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_)
table = df.set_index("date").stack() # sets date as index
table.to_frame(name='Amount').to_excel('output.xlsx') # names the column: Amount and outputs to an xlsx file
```

Prints:

```
date               
2017  lions             20
      total members    150
2016  lions             10
      total members    140
2015  lions              5
      total members    100
2014  lions             50
      total members    150
dtype: int64
```

---

**A comment on your original post**

In the future, you can easily share your dataframe here with:

```
df.head().to_dict() # .head() return first 5 rows
```

This sample outputs:

```
{'date': {0: 2017, 1: 2016, 2: 2015, 3: 2014},
 'lions': {0: 20, 1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 50},
 'total members': {0: 150, 1: 140, 2: 100, 3: 150}}
```

Comment: Really sincerly thanks to you Anton ! I tried your code and it works! However when i try to do so, without creating the table first - i read the data from csv file and get the the dateframe, it can not find the name ("date"), which is very strange

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `melt` and `set_index`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_file = StringIO("""date,2017,2016,2015,2014
total members, 150, 140, 100, 150
lions, 20, 10, 5, 25
demokrats, 60, 50, 15, 25
liberals, 20, 5, 40, 25
partizans, 50, 75, 40, 25""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

df_out= (df.rename(columns={'date':'Parties'})
           .melt(id_vars='Parties',var_name='Date',value_name='Amount')
           .set_index(['Date','Parties']))

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                    Amount
Date Parties              
2017 total members     150
     lions              20
     demokrats          60
     liberals           20
     partizans          50
2016 total members     140
     lions              10
     demokrats          50
     liberals            5
     partizans          75
2015 total members     100
     lions               5
     demokrats          15
     liberals           40
     partizans          40
2014 total members     150
     lions              25
     demokrats          25
     liberals           25
     partizans          25
```

Comment: Thank You So much Scott Boston!

Comment: @BEAst Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer if it helped you.  Thanks!